# Min-heap vs Self Balancing BST to maintain top N Elements

Tags: data-structures, heap, time-complexity, binary-search-tree

We are using a `Map<CompanyId, companyObject>` to store companies. And `companyObject` has a variable `totalStocksTradedToday` according to which `min-Heap<CompanyObject>` maintains top `k` companies with maximum  trading in the market that day. Live input of stocks being traded for companies is coming in.  So accordingly we update the `min-Heap`. Time complexity of a updating `min-heap` is

> `O(k) = O(1)(find Min element) + O(k)(search if company already exist on heap) + O(log k)(insert in min-heap)`

Is there a way to improve on this time complexity ? What if we use `Self Balancing BST` in place of `min-Heap`. Time complexity will be

> `O(logK) = O(log k)(find min) + O(log k)(searching) + O(log k)(insertion)`

Comment: `O(k)(search if company already exist on heap)` can be reduced to `O(1)` if it's indexed in a hashtable.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann can you go ahead and explain how will you index a heap element in a hashtable.

Comment: Every time you insert into the heap, you insert into the hashtable. Same on removal. When you check to see if the heap contains an element, you can check the hashtable, instead. This is essentially how a hash index in a database works.